# SQL inside c# in not updating

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to update points in my SQL Server database but when the code arrives at

```
addUPDATE.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

nothing happens. I am a first time user of SQL like this so I don't know if I am doing something wrong or what.

```
if (reader.HasRows) 
{
    SqlCommand addUPDATE = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [User] SET Points = Points + @i WHERE Username = @us", Data.DataBase);

    addUPDATE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@us", Username);
    addUPDATE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", i);

    addUPDATE.ExecuteNonQuery();

    await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(Username + " dodali: " + i.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return;
} 
else 
{
    await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Oseba ne obstaja v sistemu").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: "nothing happened" means what exactly? I must say: this code is very strange. You appear to be executing a second command while you have the first open. You are using `reader.HasRows` without actually reading them, which indicates you probably should have just used `ExecuteScalar` or perhaps do it in one batch. And `Data.DataBase` indicates you are caching the connection object. You should never do this, instead dispose your connection command and reader objects with `using`. You should also not have any complex or long-running code such as `await SendMessageAsync` while the connection is open

Comment: Your posted code never sets either "Username" or "i"

Comment: I think you are probably getting an exception because the reader is using the connection when your command tries to execute. Are you throwing away exceptions?

Comment: *I am a first time user of SQL* - I'd start with a tutorial on Entity Framework then, and work down to using raw sql if it becomes necessary

Comment: As I see, the addUPDATE is not assigned to SqlConnection. I think you must create a command either by SqlConnection.CreateCommand or by assigning a connection to the command: addUPDATE.Connection = connection;

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)